# How to read updated redis configuration file with running redis server

Tags: redis

I made a change to redis.conf, but I don't see the changes applied to the running instance. Do I need to restart redis is order to pick up changes?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have to restart the server to get changes from redis.conf file. Alternatively you can do it in run time using `config set` command.

Read more about them on the following links 
http://redis.io/topics/config
http://redis.io/commands/config-set